# Question on notation from Quantum Computing book

Tags: quantum-computation, quantum-information

I've started reading Nielsen and Chuang's book on Quantum Computing, and didn't get far. In their first chapter on "Nomenclature and notation", I saw the following expression:

$$
\langle \psi \vert A \vert \psi \rangle \geq 0
$$

Can anybody point me to a reference that can describe what this notation means (as this is something difficult to google)?

Thanks

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bra%E2%80%93ket_notation

Comment: $\langle\psi|$ is a (row) vector, $A$ is a matrix, and $|\psi\rangle$ is a (column) vector. Hence, $\langle \psi \vert A \vert \psi \rangle$ is just a real number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called [bra-ket notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bra%E2%80%93ket_notation). More concretely, what you are seeing is the [expectation value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expectation_value_(quantum_mechanics)).

A mathematician would write, if $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix and $\psi$ is an $n\times 1$ column vector,
$$
\langle\psi|A|\psi\rangle=\psi^*A\psi.
$$
In the real case that would be $\psi^TA\psi$. Another very common notation for mathematicians would be $\langle A\psi,\psi\rangle$.

The notation $\langle\psi|A|\psi\rangle$ requires $A$ to be selfadjoint (as it usually is in QM) , because otherwise [it is incoherent](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/216851/42892).